# How do I determine where the error is when I check MAUI compatibility with maui-check?

Tags: .net, macos, maui

I use `maui-check` to check for .NET MAUI compatibility. Even though the console screen says **review the errors and correct**, I don't see any errors.

```
user@macbook ~ % maui-check                           
      _   _   _____   _____     __  __      _      _   _   ___                                           
     | \ | | | ____| |_   _|   |  \/  |    / \    | | | | |_ _|                                          
     |  \| | |  _|     | |     | |\/| |   / _ \   | | | |  | |                                           
  _  | |\  | | |___    | |     | |  | |  / ___ \  | |_| |  | |                                           
 (_) |_| \_| |_____|   |_|     |_|  |_| /_/   \_\  \___/  |___|                                          
                                                                                                         
 .NET MAUI Check v0.10.0.0 
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
This tool will attempt to evaluate your .NET MAUI development environment.
If problems are detected, this tool may offer the option to try and fix them for you, or suggest a way to
fix them yourself.

Thanks for choosing .NET MAUI!
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⏳ Synchronizing configuration... ok
⏳ Scheduling appointments... ok

 OpenJDK 11.0 Checkup...
  ✔ 11.0.10 (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/..)

 Visual Studio 8.10.0 Checkup...

 Android SDK Checkup...
  ✔ emulator (30.9.5)
  ✔ build-tools;31.0.0 (31.0.0)
  ✔ platforms;android-31 (1)
  ✔ system-images;android-31;google_apis;x86_64 (8)
  ✔ platform-tools (31.0.3)
  ✔ cmdline-tools;5.0 (5.0)

 Android Emulator Checkup...
  ✔ Emulator: Android_Emulator_31 found.

 XCode 13.1 Checkup...

 .NET SDK Checkup...
  ✔ 6.0.100 - /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.100

 .NET SDK - Workload Deduplication Checkup...

 .NET SDK - EnableWorkloadResolver.sentinel Checkup...

 .NET SDK - Workloads (6.0.100) Checkup...
  ✔ android-aot (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Android.Manifest-6.0.100 : 31.0.101-preview.10.59) installed.
  ✔ ios (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.iOS.Manifest-6.0.100 : 15.0.101-preview.10.251) installed.
  ✔ maccatalyst (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.MacCatalyst.Manifest-6.0.100 : 15.0.101-preview.10.251) installed.
  ✔ tvos (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.tvOS.Manifest-6.0.100 : 15.0.101-preview.10.251) installed.
  ✔ macos (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.macOS.Manifest-6.0.100 : 12.0.101-preview.10.251) installed.
  ✔ maui (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Maui.Manifest-6.0.100 : 6.0.101-preview.10.2068) installed.
  ✔ wasm-tools (microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.manifest-6.0.100 : 6.0.0) installed.
  ✔ microsoft-net-sdk-emscripten (microsoft.net.workload.emscripten.manifest-6.0.100 : 6.0.0) installed.
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


 There were one or more problems detected.
Please review the errors and correct them and run maui-check again.

Press enter to exit...
```

Can you guys suggest me an approach?

Environment info: `macOS Monterey` on `M1` chip, `.NET 6.0 (LTS)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is not really communicated (yet) you shouldn't really need maui-check anymore. I think it will be transformed into something that you can still use to check the prerequisites for .NET MAUI, but right now it might give you some confusion as it hasn't been updated yet.

If there is no error in the output I would trust that. It might be confused with the .NET 6 GA version that mixes up the end result. Did you actually try to run something?

If you haven't you should be able to install the .NET MAUI workload with

`dotnet workload install maui`

I think the templates should come as part of that, but if not, run

`dotnet new -i Microsoft.Maui.Templates`

And then you can create a new app with

`dotnet new maui -n MyApp`

Comment: By executing ```dotnet workload install maui``` I was seeing ```maui``` when running ```dotnet new --list```. Then run "dotnew new maui" and a maui structure is generated.